# Can I optionally include one element in a list without an else statement in python?

Tags: python, list, syntax

I know you can do something like this in python:

```
>>> conditional = False
>>> x = [1 if conditional else 2, 3, 4]
[ 2, 3, 4 ]
```

but how would I do something like this?

```
>>> conditional = False
>>> x = [1 if conditional, 3, 4]
[ 3, 4 ]
```

That is, I don't want to substitute the `1` for another number. I want to simply omit it if `conditional` is false.

Comment: There is no list comprehension here, so I removed the tag.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use concatenation:

```
x = ([1] if conditional else []) + [3, 4]
```

In other words, generate a sublist that either has the optional element in it, or is empty.

Demo:

```
>>> conditional = False
>>> ([1] if conditional else []) + [3, 4]
[3, 4]
>>> conditional = True
>>> ([1] if conditional else []) + [3, 4]
[1, 3, 4]
```

This concept works for more elements too, of course:

```
x = ([1, 2, 3] if conditional else []) + [4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 3):

Slightly faster than https://stackoverflow.com/a/18988829/1093967 in Python 3.5+ (leveraging additional unpacking generalizations introduced by PEP-448):

```
>>> timeit("([1, 2, 3] if True else []) + [4, 5, 6]")
0.10665618600614835
>>> timeit("[*([1, 2, 3] if True else []), 4, 5, 6]")
0.08992647400009446
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a slice

```
x = [1, 3, 4][not conditional:]
```

eg

```
>>> conditional = False
>>> [1, 3, 4][not conditional:]
[3, 4]
>>> conditional = True
>>> [1, 3, 4][not conditional:]
[1, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Same remark applies here as on Abhijit's answer, only more so.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Ah well this is Python not Ruby :)

Comment: To handle more than one element, define the length of the leading conditional list, and change to `condLen=3; [1,1,1,3,4][(not conditional)*condLen:]`

Comment: This must not be a serious answer...it looks so Perlish to a recent Perl escapee, and unreadable as hell.

Answer (score 1):

```
[*(1 for _i in range(1) if conditional), 2, 3, 4]
```

Learned this trick from a coworker.

Answer (score 0):

If you truly want to avoid the `else`, you could write a generator for the list items:

```
def gen_x(conditional):
    if conditional:
        yield 1
    for v in [3, 4]:
        yield v
```

Or, [since Python 3.3](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380):

```
def gen_x(conditional):
    if conditional:
        yield 1
    yield from [3, 4]
```

And then:

```
x = list(gen_x(conditional))
```