# How to return variable if it exists

Tags: python

I have the following function but it throws errors like `data` accessed before assignment when i run `foo(-1)`. I would like it to return `None`. Can we return many values from a function where one of them is conditional. I don't want to write return in a `if elif` construct.

```
def foo(x):
    if x > 1:
        data = range(0,10)
    elif x < 0:
        print 'not valid'

    return 1, 2, 3, data or None
```

Is there any other alternative to defining data in the start? Something like `return 1, 2, 3, [data if data]` using list comprehension or something

Comment: What happens if `x == 0`?

Comment: I just wanted to write a random func

Comment: You also can check whether `if 'data' in locals():` to see if data is a local variable. But it's preferred to initialize the data at the top of the function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I optionally include one element in a list without an else statement in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18988805/can-i-optionally-include-one-element-in-a-list-without-an-else-statement-in-pyth)

Comment: it didn't work in the return statement

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The current answers don't actually answer the question; they just recommend explicitly defining the variable. 
To return a variable only in the case that it exists, you should use a ternary operator:

`a if condition else b`

In this case, it looks like you could use:

```
def foo(x):
    if x > 1:
        data = range(0,10)
    elif x < 0:
        print 'not valid'
    return 1, 2, 3, data if 'data' in locals() else None
```

With this, passing any number great than 1 to foo() will return the tuple:

`(1, 2, 3, range(0, 10))`

Passing any number less than 1 will return the tuple:

`(1, 2, 3, None)`

I think that this method is preferable, because it clearly demonstrates what you're doing. You're saying "Return this thing, but if it doesn't exist, then return None." If you initialize the variable first, then that can be seen as you accidentally forgetting to set the variable under some conditions.

Comment: I think this does an excellent job of addressing the question, and reminded me that locals() exists. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 6):

Define **data** at the beginning of the function, if it's **None**, the return statement will return **None** as expected.

```
def foo(x):
    data = None
    if x > 1:
        data = range(0,10)
    elif x < 0:
        print 'not valid'

    return 1, 2, 3, data
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using a dictionary's .get() method?

Example:

```
>>> # this makes an empty dictionary,
>>> #  then tries to get the value with key 'data',
>>> #  and returns 'default' if the key is not found
>>> #  (or if the found value is None)
>>> {}.get('data', 'default')
'default'
>>> # .get()'s default parameter is optional, and will
>>> #  be set to None if you don't provide a value
>>> print({}.get('data'))
None
>>> # it's worth being careful about ranges
>>> {'data': range(0, 10)}.get(data)
range(0, 10)
>>> # you may want the actual numbers instead of the range generator
>>> {'data': [datum for datum in range(0, 10)]}.get(data)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

For your example:

```
def foo(x):
    my_dict = dict()
    if x > 1:
        my_dict['data'] = range(10)  # range(0,10) == range(10)
    elif x < 0:
        print 'not valid'
    return 1, 2, 3, my_dict.get('data')
```

WARNING:

The above will return the tuple with types `(int, int, int, range)` or types `(int, int, int, None)`. If you wanted types to be more like `(int, int, int, int, int, ..., int)` in the valid case, then I would recommend switching up your function, like:

```
def foo(x):
    solution = [1,2,3]
    if x > 1:
        solution.extend([n for n in range(10)])
    else:
        solution.append(None)
    if x < 0:
        print('x required to be positive number')
    return solution
```

Answer (score 0):

You initialize data only if x is greater than 1. If x is not greater than 1, then data is not initialize but you try to return it. You need to put data before in the very beginning:

```
def foo(x):
    data = None
    if x > 1:
        data = range(0,10)
    elif x < 0:
        print 'not valid'

    return 1, 2, 3, data
```

Comment: Keep in mind this returns a tuple with types (int, int, int, range).

If you want the actual integers to be filled in, you'll need to do a list comprehension instead.